# decompose function show a seasonal graph but there is no correlation in the correlation plot past lag 12 for a monthly dataset. What does it mean?

Tags: r, time-series, acf-pacf, decomposition

I generated a TS out of a monthly data.

TQ_volume_ts <- ts(csv_file[4:39,"Volume"], start=c(2019,01), frequency = 12)

When i apply the decompose function I get the following result:
[image: Decompose Plot]

Now I applied the acf and pacf function to the same TS:
[image: ACF Plot]

[image: PACF Plot]

From the autocorrelation plots I see no correlation regarding to the 12th month lags (lag 1.0). Does it mean, even though the decompose can still plot a seasonal plot, my TS has no seasonality?

Complementing the question based on whuber answer. See below the ACF and PACF plots after differencing:

[image: ACF Plot after 1st order differencing]
[image: PACF Plot after 1st order differencing]

Comment: Difference the series before looking for seasonality, because the decomposition reveals a near-linear trend whose magnitude overwhelms everything else.

Comment: Thanks for your time whuber.